# What type to use when implement RouteComponentProps on react typescript component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom, react-typescript

I am trying to make my first component that receive parameter using react-router-dom.
This is my component:

```
const ProductDetailsPage: React.FC<IPage & RouteComponentProps<any>> = (props: Props) => {

    useEffect(() => {
        const id = props.match.params.id;
    }
    return <h1>product details</h1>
}

interface Props {
    match: {
        params: {
            id: string | undefined;
        };
    };
}
```

Here eslint show me a warning that I should not use `any` but I don't understand what type to set here.
Also I wrote `props: Props` but I don't know if this is correct way to do it like this.

**UPDATE more code for preview:**

```
export default interface IPage {
    name: string;
}

const routes: IRoute[] = [
    {
        path: '/products/:id',
        name: 'details',
        component: ProductDetailsPage,
        exact: true,
    },
];

const ProductsPage: React.FC<IPage> = () => {
    const match = useRouteMatch();

    return (
        <div>
            <h4>This is products page</h4>
            <div>
                <Link to={`${match.url}/44`}>Product 44</Link>
                <Link to={`${match.url}/45`}>Product 44</Link>
                <Link to={`${match.url}/46`}>Product 44</Link>
            </div>
            <Switch>
                {routes.map((route, index) => {
                    return (
                        <Route
                            key={index}
                            path={route.path}
                            render={(props: RouteComponentProps<any>) => (
                                <route.component name={route.name} {...props} {...route.props} />
                            )}
                        />
                    );
                })}
            </Switch>
        </div>
    );
};

interface Props {
    match: {
        params: {
            id: string | undefined;
        };
    };
}

const ProductDetailsPage: React.FC<IPage & RouteComponentProps<Props>> = (props) => {
    const [message, setMessage] = useState<string>('');

    useEffect(() => {
        const id = props.match.params.id;

        if (id) {
            setMessage(`Show details for product: ${id}`);
        } else {
            setMessage(`No parameter passed`);
        }
    }, [props.match.params.id]);

    return <h4>{message}</h4>;
};

export default withRouter(ProductDetailsPage);
```

Answer (score 1):

The generic (`T`) in `RouteComponentProps<T>` defines the params type.

A param value is always a `string` or `undefined`.

If the params are unknown it would probably be better to use `Record<string, string | undefined>` to type the params.

```
type Params = { id: string | undefined; };

const Test: React.FC<RouteComponentProps<Params>> = ({
    match: { params: { id } }
}) => {
    const idIsStringOrUndefined: string | undefined = id;

    return null;
}
```

Also props should be typed automatically by typing the component with `React.FC<RouteComponentProps<Params>>`.

Comment: If I do like that I got: `Type 'ProductDetailsParams' does not satisfy the constraint '{ match?: string | undefined; }'.
  Types of property 'match' are incompatible.
    Type '{ params: { id: string | undefined; }; }' is not assignable to type 'string'.`

Comment: I simplified the example slightly, but match should never be `string | undefined` when provided by `react-router` where is that type originating from?

Comment: I updated question with fool code. So short tour is: I have routes which I am rendering dynamically in ProductsPage and ProductDetailsPage is child route inside of it.

Comment: The generic of `RouteComponentProps<T>` only expects the type definition for the params property of match and not the complete type of match. `Props` interface should be `interface Props { id: string | undefined; }`

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAehHEFMDtIJwIYBsAEBBADhuB7BBjAC2AEsBbDHOAFxQCoUEBnFAJUgNoDNcyUByOB3zV+AblIUqtAN6scAV2qQAwjimxo1AAq4MTAL4oe6gUM4BaXEvgWAJuvHBn1AJ4ZIKACryb2hIhkLAC8KDLAKCgYAQhkAHKxkABcTNRwJNAA5mIowAbOYACStPgI0CgARp44XIzQrihuHgB0KABSCqnGVChCXPAw+J5MHvgkXK4ZmYwsZSg4FQBWkCLNwE2ePorKAMrUCMoooeGRqQeQujgeNK5JCtAA1tA4AO7QOWDsGEgEnvdPr3KLxI1EIjUInk4CmQjXckDW+QKIF8yjUGhgOj0TAAPABNRRwFEXGJBAA0KD2BxI+DUWkgAA9aMcjOT8Qo4JTlAARA4II51VwAPnWcO8mAwl30-KJaMomkxVxxWz8JKYpJkBlJyt2+2UgpQADIwhEUK4CQB5UHwSVMAASAzuj2ebwkiPwOGgXXF-IAFNhFUkvOKbQBKI768ImsBxV6mxQoUrlAhDJgsaKBFjA0HbAUoEiphTwk3uz20ZOQVP+QL8-36ZpkA5EZrp2JMZskhJkSASSLR2NmhQJubl1MoM6HOy8lBZwg5soNfNMQtrSIlrrjyA8-Y1rHNJA4UrUEge5ob0+6i56eBuCR5ZygEBsuAUnBIJTH6AuUVeKut-kyEg7BSNIphQAAfFB7jsSAuAySA7AMW8MmUOAuF+FBCn8TJPA1W8Nm8S47AUEQuUgfYSCQJgbX5TCEGww02G2VR1DlDEbWxH9VWFe811oQjiOoUjyMorDkjYYRqGaAAxFQOP4kiyIQCiqKxfVQj9LEw2CCNnEiSJ2E4ZpOkgABRLh+hEH0fS0nS9LshMPS6QCd0VetG0IdsM2aQCez0gwQ1vOyhGodlymxQgAEZBX9IiRBQaDhJxEBIuFfIgA) to understand RouteComponentProps.

```
type TParams = {id:string | undefined};

type TProductDetailsProps = IPage & RouteComponentProps<TParams>

const ProductDetailsPage: React.FC<TProductDetailsProps> = (props) => {

useEffect(() => {
    const id = props.match.params.id;
});

return <h1>product details</h1>
 }
```

Comment: I tried that too and I am getting match is missing in props validation. I will update question.